# Blocks in a for-loop under the hood?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I read an article on loops and it said that it was better to use for-loops rather than methods (like forEach) whenever possible. The reason for that is a higher performance of for-loop due to not creating a new context on every iteration.

But how does a block in for-loop work? While a function has it's own context that could be removed from the call stack with all it's variables, what happens with variables in a block defined on a previous iteration? How do the same variables are recreated on every iteration? How does a memory work in this case?

Comment: Depends how you declare your variables. `var`s live for the entire function scope. `let` and `const` live only for the duration of their containing block.

Comment: "_better to use for-loops rather than methods_" Maybe a bit opinionated, but you should always prefer (array) methods instead of a `for` loop. Semantic methods are much clearer and more understandable than a `for` loop. If, and only if a method loop appears to be a bottleneck in your code, then consider to use a `for` loop.

Comment: In a for-loop, the block of code is executed multiple times with the loop variables being updated on each iteration. This offers better performance and more efficient memory usage than methods like forEach, which create a new context on each iteration. 

The variables in a for-loop are not "recreated" on each iteration, but rather their values are updated. Once the loop is completed, the memory space used by the loop variables will be freed up

Comment: @YosvelQuintero You haven't heard about [block scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block#block_scoping_rules_with_let_const_class_or_function_declaration_in_strict_mode) ..?

Comment: "_but you should always prefer (array) methods_" - @Teemu For methods like `.map()`/`.every()`/etc. I agree. But I find a regular `for..of` a lot better readable than a `.forEach()`. Besides performance it also allows you to easily break out of the loop and it is `async` friendly.

Comment: @Ivar True, I should had added "_case-dependently_" to my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Ok Pro Tip: Anyone can write articles and not every article is to be followed blindly.

It is true that For Loops are more performant than regular array methods, but the difference is almost always insignificant, and you should only worry about that when you're working on a strictly time-bound module or project. And I mean really really strictly time-bound (maybe like a hackathon challenge or some other work).

Otherwise, you should use the array functions as they are easier to read and understand, and make your code more maintainable.

As for how for-loops work, it depends on what was used to declare the iterator. If you use const or let which are block scoped, then what happens is:

1. The variables are declared.
2. Whatever needs to be executed, is executed.
3. When the end of the block is reached, the variable is garbage collected and the memory is freed for the next iteration.